# Routing Error uninitialized constant Meetups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, routes, controller

I am currently stuck getting a Routing Error for uninitialized constant Meetups

```
class MeetupsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_meetup, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  def create
    @meetup = Meetup.new(host: current_user)
    @meetup.save
    redirect_to meetup_create_path(Wicked::FIRST_STEP, meetup_id: @meetup.id)
  end
end
```

This is my create function inside my MeetupsController, as you can see the controller name is plural and the file name is 'meetups_controller.rb'

Below is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
  resources :meetups, except: [:show] do
    resources :create, controller: 'meetups/setup'
    resources :participations, only: [:new]
    member do
      get "create/review", to: 'meetups/setup#review'
    end
  end

  root to: 'pages#home'
  get 'join_meetup', to: 'pages#join_meetup'
  get 'events', to: 'pages#events'
  get 'landing', to: 'pages#landing'
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please paste error line. By chance, is error for Meetup or it is Meetups?

Comment: 'Routing Error
uninitialized constant Meetups'

This is all it says along with the rails route which just links to the folder the project is stored in

Answer (score 0):

Error trace would be more helpful.

But looking at `resources :create, controller: 'meetups/setup'` in routes file, I could guess that the Rails application is Expecting namespaced controller as `Meetups::SetupController`.

So you need to change your controller accordingly. You need to create a namespaced controller or may be a scoped controller.

Reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the setupController, turns out the Folder the setupcontroller was in was called meeetups with an extra 'e'

Comment: Ohh... See if you would have copy-pasted error traced someone would have noticed that extra `e`.
Nevermind if my answer was helpful to you then please accept answer and upvote it. Thanks.